# Animateinline works in Beamer but not report

Tags: beamer, animate, parbox

I have the following code that works in Beamer (first time using animateinline btw) and would like to add to a pdf text, but when I transition to report, it throws errors:

Missing \endcsnmame inserted,
Missing number, treated as zero,
Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted),
Extra }, or forgotten /endgroup,
etc.

Any thoughts, or can I not use animations in report?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{animate}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{animateinline}[autoplay,loop,controls]{1} 
  \multiframe{24}{i=2+1}{\parbox{\textwidth}{
\includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{MomDistZ/listMD\i}
\includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{BandsZ/ListBand\i}
\\
\includegraphics[width=.33\textwidth]{SingPairAmpZ/ListPairAmp\i}
\includegraphics[width=.33\textwidth]{TripDnPairAmpZ/ListTripDn\i}
\includegraphics[width=.33\textwidth]{TripUpPairAmpZ/ListTripUp\i}  
}}
\end{animateinline}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange!

Comment: Thank you, I've been a viewer for quite some time, but have found answers before I needed to ask. Thank you for your quick reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two problems:

- the `graphicx` package is missing
- the `frame` environment is not defined in `article` class

(You're images were slightly too big and caused overfull boxes)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{animate}
\begin{document}
%\begin{frame}
\begin{animateinline}[autoplay,loop,controls]{1}%
    \multiframe{24}{i=2+1}{%
      \parbox{.95\textwidth}{%
        \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image}%
            \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image}%

            \includegraphics[width=.33\linewidth]{example-image}%
            \includegraphics[width=.33\linewidth]{example-image}%
            \includegraphics[width=.33\linewidth]{example-image}%
        }%
    }%
\end{animateinline}%
%\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You could also keep the frame(s) and use the `beamerarticle` package.

Comment: @erik Please feel free to post an answer with this idea!

Comment: Thank you for your quick replies, it was indeed that I forgot graphicx. I left the frames because it worked in Beamer as written. My dissertation is long and I often ensure new content works before adding to my long text. It takes longer than usual to build. This is likely due to latex screaming at me about underfull hbox badness. I used \textwidth because one example I incorporated used it and never changed what works. But I think I get why it's wrong. Should I use \linewidth on singular images too?

Comment: @Sureau Unless for special situations (e.g. inside itemizations) it does not make much difference. I myself usually use `\textwidth`

Answer (score 2):

In addition to adding the `graphicx` package, as pointed out by @samcarter, you could keep the frames and use the `beamerarticle` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}
\usepackage{animate}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{animateinline}[autoplay,loop,controls]{1}%
    \multiframe{24}{i=2+1}{%
      \parbox{.95\textwidth}{%
        \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image}%
            \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image}%

            \includegraphics[width=.33\linewidth]{example-image}%
            \includegraphics[width=.33\linewidth]{example-image}%
            \includegraphics[width=.33\linewidth]{example-image}%
        }%
    }%
\end{animateinline}%
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting. Does `beamerarticle` simply neutralise the `frame` environments?

Comment: @AlexG It appears to translate the `frame` environment into something like `\noindent\textbf{‹frametitle›}\par`. Other elements are also translated, such as `block` and `alertblock` environments. There is also an article-specific overlay specification, which allows you to add to the article what you would otherwise explain during a presentation with `\only<article>{}`.

Comment: Thank you for your quick replies, but this is for a dissertation and I'm using a report template. The issue was resolved by samcarter in that in my minimal example I forgot the graphicx package. The frames were still included in my example above because it worked in Beamer. But thank you again for your help.

Comment: @Sureau You're welcome. For future reference, the beamerarticle package works with the report documentclass as well.